# Android Studio: Client not ready yet

Tags: android, debugging, server, client, javascript-debugger

While launching an app, I am getting a message " Client not ready yet". Also, my device is showing" Waiting for debugger to attach ", followed by "Unfortunately, android app has stopped working". I have tried every possible solution available on discussion forums, but no solution is applying here.I also tried running a simple HELLO WORLD app to know whether there is some issue with my app code, but the same message is been shown. I tried the following things:

1. Reinstalling the deice drivers
2. Reinstalling the android studio
3. Installing LLDB
4. Using different device, different cable and port
5. adding *android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();* to the manifest file
6. Changing setting to MTP only
7. Removing all breakpoints

But nothing worked. What could be the root cause of this problem??

Comment: You don't have log at all?

Comment: What about your phone mode?

Comment: Please check the picture.Launch Options is Default Activity
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKTO1.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkhRT.png

Comment: Thanks so much @Pluto :)

Answer (score 17):

The activity has to be exported to be accessible from adb. If the Activity has an `intent-filter` it is exported by default. Otherwise add the exported flag:

```
<activity
    android:name=".my.MyActivity"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

This is the error you get when the activity is not exported and you run

`adb shell am start -n "com.example/com.example.my.MyActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`

Error:

```
Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example/.my.MyActiviy } from null (pid=26721, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10304
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2694)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:875)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:359)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:100)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:251)
```

Comment: Shit! Now I understand why editing the configuration to start another activity did never work!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**[This answer is obsolete for latest versions of Android Studio]**

This worked for me :

Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration

You need to **tick** *Enable ADB Integration*

Comment: The Tools > Android menu doesn't exist in Android studio 3.1.2

Answer (score 1):

If this is a transient issue then in most cases I have found restarting Android Studio fixed the issue.

In one case a Windows restart seemed to fix the problem. A reboot of the device did not.

It was a transient issue which happened just occasionally for a few days but eventually started happening every time and therefore stopped all work.

I was working with two different Android Studio projects open at the same time, both running (different) apps on the same device (but not at the same time).

I may have opened the Device File Explorer on both projects.

Answer (score 0):

If the error does **NOT** come from AndroidManifest (like my situation), you can try this:

- Tool -> Android -> TURN OFF [Enable ADB Integration]
- Run -> Run "appname"
- When you app shows the message "Waiting for debug", select Run -> **Attach Debugger to Android process** -> Choose the package name of your app under Deive's name.
- Observe Logcat and trace out where your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

add those lines into your manifest file

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

inside your activity tag

Answer (score 0):

Check Run/Debug Configurations.

Go to **Run/Debug Configurations** > **Launch Options** > **Launch** and select ***Default* Activity**.

I accidentally switched it to **Nothing** and the application stopped running after installation.

[image: select Default Activity]

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio 3.4.1 you might get:

```
 No apk changes detected since the last installation, skipping installation of /apk/debug/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop
$ adb shell am start -n ".StartingScreenActivity" 
-a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet...
```

> **The Tools > Android menu** doesn't exist in Android studio 3.1.2 +

In the case on -> Run - 'run' app - 
a device in the bracket show (**NULL**)

In my case as shown in a picture -> Android 8.0.0, API26
[Android (NULL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaOmw.png)

Open: **Tools ->  Conection Asistent** and pres **Next**
[Tools -> Conection Asistent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeD8O.png)

You might need to Restart ADB server in Connection Assistant and you should be good to go.