# I try to use google play services as authentication in my Android app project but it display this error

Tags: google-play-services

Errors:

```
02/15 09:33:30: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\recevienotfirebase\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.hp.recevienotfirebase
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.hp.recevienotfirebase"
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.hp.recevienotfirebase/com.example.hp.recevienotfirebase.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 2360 on device Nexus_6P_API_24 [emulator-5554]
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hp.recevienotfirebase-1/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.hp.recevienotfirebase, real application class is null.

              [ 02-15 09:33:38.693  1497: 1520 D/         ]
              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8fdb9800, tid 1520
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hp.recevienotfirebase-1/lib/x86
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10012
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 91568628
V/FA: Collection enabled
V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.hp.recevienotfirebase, 1:1056127560632:android:663d67b615c99e63
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
        adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.hp.recevienotfirebase
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
V/FA: State of service unknown
V/FA: Checking service availability
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9452470
D/FA: Service container out of date
V/FA: Setting useService: true
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9452470
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 51631
W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed

                  [ 02-15 09:33:52.817  2360: 2360 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9e59ea40, tid 2360
W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
V/FA: Session started, time: 61634
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _s, Bundle[{_o=auto, _sc=MainActivity, _si=-2727167516359703917}]
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9452470
W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
W/FA: Tasks have been queued for a long time
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9452470
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525954/android-studio-client-not-ready-yet) which states that you'll get this error when the activity is not exported. Be noted that the activity has to be exported to be accessible from adb.

Also, based from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754358/firebase-android-skipping-initialization), you have to add the following to your android manifest: `<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>` or maybe the problem was that the `onTokenRefresh()` method was not called when the app was starting. Try calling [`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) in the MainActivity and see if it works.