# "Client not ready yet" when trying to start release build variant in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to run the release build variant of my app, it results in the message "Client not ready yet" and it does not go on...strangely, this happens only when the run is performed on my mobile phone, not when doing it in the android emulator (Nexus 5X). The debug release works perfectly, both on my device and in the emulator. How can I fix this issue? I already tried some solutions provided in similar questions but none of them were useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure device's screen is on, and if the app does not launch automatically after installing open it manually

Comment: device's screen is on and the app launches automatically...

Comment: Refer this link [Android Studio: Client not ready yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525954/android-studio-client-not-ready-yet) i hope your query solve.